# Sort merged array by array value in Twig?

Tags: templating, sorting

I have two Instagram API responses that I want to merge, by the photo's `created_time`. Is there a way to do that in Twig?

Right now I am just using this

```
{% set instagram = <data> %}
{% set community = <data> %}
{% set feed = instagram|merge(community) %}

    {% for photo in feed %}
        <img src="{{photo.images.low_resolution.url}}" alt="">
        <br />
    {% endfor %}
```

Each photo has a created_time string that I'd like to sort the array by, is that possible without creating a custom Twig extension?

The sortByField plugin looked promising and sort of what I want, but it was directly aimed at Craft entry manipulation. Is there anything hacky that could be done?

Comment: Since the only way to sort a multidimensional array in PHP is with a usort and thus a custom function based on your array, I think you'd have to create a custom twig filter. You could use one of mine as a base. It's very simple, so pretty easy to pick apart: https://github.com/jpeacock/highestmultiple

Comment: Yeah it looks that way! I've already written a primitive plugin for getting the first paragraph of an Rich Text Field so i should be able to hack something together. Which is a pain, because the sortByField plugin gets quite close. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is only possible with a custom [Twig Extension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html), since sorting a multidimensional array can't be done with Twig itself.

I've written a plugin which extends Twigs sorting methods, which you could use as a base: [Craft-TwigBetterSort](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigBetterSort).

Just add this to the [*TwigBetterSortTwigExtension.php*](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigBetterSort/blob/master/twigbettersort/twigextensions/TwigBetterSortTwigExtension.php)

```php
public function twig_sort($array, $method='asort', $sort_flag='SORT_REGULAR')
{
    // ....
    case 'custom_sort_name':
        usort($array, array('TwigBetterSortTwigExtension','custom_sort_function'));
        break;
    // ....
}

private function custom_sort_function($a, $b)
{
    // Do stuff with your array
}
```

and use it like this in your templates:

```twig
{% array|sort('custom_sort_name') %}
```

Comment: hmm not having any luck with this. feel like im missing something.  I have object similar to the original question and i have this...

case 'dateSort':
   usort($array, array('TwigBetterSortTwigExtension','created_date_sort'));
   break;

...

public function created_date_sort($a, $b) {
 if ($a.created_at == $b.created_at) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a.created_at < $b.created_at) ? -1 : 1;
  }

Comment: @KeithMancuso Just tried your code on a random array: `{% set array = { 2: '5', 4: '6', 1: '5', 3: '6', 2: '7', 4: '8' } %}` and it got re-sorted. What exactly isn't working for you? (Share bigger code using [CraftBin](http://craftb.in/) )

Comment: Sorry you are right it's working, not sure what was going on but thanks

Answer (score 13):

The [SuperSort](https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/SuperSort) Plugin is built for use cases exactly such as this. It allows you to render each object in your array using a Twig object template and sort the array based on the rendered value.

For example, in OP's case, we could sort the combined array by the `created_time` variable like this:

```
...
{% set feed = instagram|merge(community) %}
{% set sortedFeed = feed | supersort('sortAs', '{created_time}') %}
```

*(The plugin parses `{created_time}` — a Craft '[micro-template](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#renderObjectTemplate-detail)' — into `{{object.created_time}}`, which provides the value by which the array is sorted.)*

If the property of interest happened to be different between two arrays, we could include a conditional or ternary operator in the micro-template to differentiate them:

```
{% set sortedFeed = feed | supersort('sortAs', '{{ object.current_time is defined ?: object.someOtherProperty }}') %}
```

Comment: There's a download link on the docs page: http://michaelrog.com/craft/supersort

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the same. Making some sort of feed with multidimensional data array. Like combining comments feed with entries and twitter. Michael can you give us a simple example of to use your plugin? De docs are hard to understand for me.

Comment: Surely — I've added a code example to my answer.

Comment: @michael Great little plugin, thanks so much for making this.